# Ideal contents of a reference letter for PhDs seeking industry jobs

Tags: recommendation-letter, industry

The majority of PhD holders do not stay on in academia, but rather move on to jobs in industry far away from the area of their PhDs. Given that the content of the PhD is not directly relevant (the common wisdom is that a PhD holder has "learned how to learn"), what should one include in reference letters for an academic applying for industry jobs? What qualities are those in industry looking for? Does the answer vary for newly minted PhDs vs more experienced researchers?

Comment: Are you asking from the perspective of a letter writer? Note that there are very different kinds of "industry" jobs. Some are a _lot_ like academia, others not at all. There are probably distinctions by field, as well.

Comment: @Buffy the question came up in a discussion and I realised I didn’t have a good answer. Answers addressing any fields of academia/industry would be welcome!

Comment: "Industry" is a big place, but in my experience, industry employers do not ask for letters of recommendation at all. Instead, they will ask for "references," which they will contact by phone or e-mail. If you are in a field or part of the world where industry employers really do want written letters of recommendation, it might be worth specifying.

Answer (score -3):

There are a lot of examples of recomendation letters in Internet for both, industry and academia. So, you can take any of them and present your skills and experience in the corresponding way.